# Local website won't work, shows part of source code

Tags: php, macos

I set up a local website. It worked more or less. Rebooted the computer to setup timezone like shown here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090831101932728

And now when I go to `http://localhost/index.php` I don't see the site anymore, but only a part of it's code: `$v) { protect_array($arr[$k]); } } else ......[two pages of the unformatted code here]`

The full function it fails in looks like this:

```
function protect_array(&$arr) {
    if (is_array($arr)) {
        foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
            protect_array($arr[$k]);
        }
    } else {
```

I have svn and I checked that any part of the site code was not changed unexpectedly.

I tried to restart appache: `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

I have no experience with web-programming and this looks for me completely strange. When typically such a problem would appear?
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: View the page source. Do you see the whole source code? Or only part of it?

Comment: @JohnConde, the whole. Starting from "<? .."

Comment: Did you use <? or <?php to mark the beginning of PHP code? You should get in the habit of using the "long open tag" <?php. If you insist on using "short open tag" <? you need to specifically tell PHP to recognize them.

Comment: @PhilPerry, how do I tell php this? This is not my code and it worked before reboot unchanged.

Comment: You should have some means of using a PHP configuration or initialization file (such as _php.ini_). A directive would go in there to enable short open tags. You're better off changing <? to <?php. (It's possible that => is being recognized as some sort of short tag) As for why the reboot changed something, it sounds like someone made a change that wasn't put into a configuration file, so it was ignored on reboot.

Comment: @PhilPerry, yes, that worked. The problem was that I created /etc/php.ini file by copying, that had short_open_tag = Off, meanwhile default is On. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't running it as PHP, are you ;)

You need to be running a server on your machine, and the URL needs to be `http://localhost/yourfile.php` or similar, for PHP to be processed and run.

Comment: How to run it as PHP? Why did it work before reboot?